# Incrementing number in variable name

Tags: php, html

#### Background

I have a `for` loop creating a table of inputs for an html form:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
  echo '<select name="waldo_'.$i.'" id="waldo_'.$i.'">
      <option value="">...</option>
      <option value="foo">Foo</option>
      <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
    <label for="foo_'.$i.'">Foo '.$i.'</label>
    <input id="foo_'.$i.'" type="text" value="" name="foo_'.$i.'">
    <label for="bar_'.$i.'">Bar '.$i.'</label>
    <input id="bar_'.$i.'" type="text" value="" name="bar_'.$i.'">';
}
```

On submit, this populates a database.

#### Problem

Each submission needs to be editable.  When I return to the form (as an admin) I need to see everything that was stored in the database by a particular user.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
  echo '<select name="waldo_'.$i.'" id="waldo_'.$i.'">
      <option value="">...</option>
      <option value="foo"';
  if($row['waldo_'.$i] == "foo") echo " selected='selected'";
  echo '>Foo</option>
      <option value="bar"';
  if($row['waldo_'.$i] == "bar") echo " selected='selected'"; 
  echo '>Bar</option>
    </select>
    <label for="foo_'.$i.'">Foo '.$i.'</label>
    <input id="foo_'.$i.'" type="text" value="'./*...*/.'" name="foo_'.$i.'">
    <label for="bar_'.$i.'">Bar '.$i.'</label>
    <input id="bar_'.$i.'" type="text" value="'./*...*/.'" name="bar_'.$i.'">';
}
```

My `select` properly "selects" the correct option, but I don't seem to be able to populate the text input values in a similar manner.
Somehow I need to `echo` the content in `$foo_1`, `$foo_2`, `$foo_3`, ..., `$foo_x`.

I have tried using `$foo_.$i` but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a simple solution to this problem? Or is there a better method to format everything?

Comment: This is really where you should learn to use arrays

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm in the process of moving content between systems.  The forms are all pre-written.  Using arrays would make sense to me, however this is what was being used in the current system.  If it is possible to solve this without reformatting all of the forms, I believe it would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding your question:

```
$_POST["foo_".$i]
```

Should show you the submitted data.

EDIT: Or maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
  echo '<select name="waldo_'.$i.'" id="waldo_'.$i.'">
      <option value="">...</option>
      <option value="foo"';
  if(isset($row['waldo_'.$i]) && $row['waldo_'.$i] == "foo") echo " selected='selected'";
  echo '>Foo</option>
      <option value="bar"';
  if(isset($row['waldo_'.$i]) && $row['waldo_'.$i] == "bar") echo " selected='selected'"; 
  echo '>Bar</option>
    </select>
    <label for="foo_'.$i.'">Foo '.$i.'</label>
    <input id="foo_'.$i.'" type="text" value="';
  if(isset($row['foo_'.$i]) && $row['foo_'.$i] != "") echo $row['foo_'.$i];
    echo '" name="foo_'.$i.'">
    <label for="bar_'.$i.'">Bar '.$i.'</label>
    <input id="bar_'.$i.'" type="text" value="';
  if(isset($row['bar_'.$i]) && $row['bar_'.$i] != "") echo $row['bar_'.$i];
    echo '" name="bar_'.$i.'">';
}
```

Comment: If it is coming from the database, it may be in `$row["foo_".$i]`

Comment: @DarkAshelin This would help if I were using php for validation. We can use `_POST` to keep the field populated if the user enters something incorrectly.  However in this particular case I am trying to pull from a database.  I believe that `$_POST` is form field specific.

Comment: @DarkAshelin This still wouldn't _quite_ work.  When a user goes to the page for the first time (nothing is pulled from the database) I think that it would choke when it runs into the unknown variable `$row`.  Right?

Comment: No, that's what the isset($row) is for. It checks if the variable exists, and if not, leaves the input empty.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.  I was misunderstanding `isset'.